# MongoDb rename _id field into something else

Tags: mongodb

I have an existing mongodb collection that have import problem.

Below is a sample of the stored data:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c40434f7aacb3871839c86c"), 
    "content" : {
        "$reql_type$" : "BINARY", 
        "data" : "FILE_CONTENT_HERE"
    }, 
    "id" : "974e7ea1-ba14-42f0-82db-c23d4026d8ed"
}
```

now, you can see that there is `_id` and `id`.
`_id` is in `ObjectId`, while `id` is `String`.

now, I would like to use `id` as the `_id` field while removing the old `_id`.

Importing the data again is a `no-no` since the data is really big.

Is there an easier way to do this? (1) rename `_id` into `remove_me`. (2) rename `id` into `_id`.

Thanks!